# Name trigger (ZABBIX)

Tags: zabbix

I need to do

```
FREE PLACE ON DISC O: ({ITEM.LASTVALUE}) FROM (total disk space)
```

Trigger expression

```
{sql01:vfs.fs.size[O:,free].last(0)}<21474836480
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean "FREE SPACE" but info you've provided doesn't help me to understand your needs enough. Provide more context. What you need to do? Trigger action? Change value? Change behavior?

Comment: No, it’s TOTAL SPACE =)
It’s more convenient to check messages on a mobile phone without opening the entire trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to see the used/total space in the trigger title, there's no need to put that information in the trigger itself: starting from Zabbix 4.4, it's available as an optional information/column in the Problems page:

It's "none" by default, but can be selected separately or within problem name:

[image]

The part highligthed in green is added:

[image]

See the documentation for: [operational_data_of_problems](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/monitoring/problems#operational_data_of_problems)

Comment: Thank you for what you need. The truth will have to upgrade to at least 4.4, I have 4.0 now.
And the need to see what is common in the name of the trigger is due to the fact that it is convenient to view triggers from a mobile phone.